# java code to search specified string array contains in vector or not

Tags: java, arrays, vector

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Vector fullVector = new Vector();
        Vector simpleVector = new Vector();

        String[] fullVectorData = new String[2];
        fullVectorData[0] = "MAP0003";
        fullVectorData[1] = ",";
        fullVector.add(fullVectorData);

        String[] fullVectorData1 = new String[2];
        fullVectorData1[0] = "MAP0004";
        fullVectorData1[1] = ",";
        fullVector.add(fullVectorData1);

        String[] simpleData = new String[2];
        simpleData[0] = "MAP0003";
        simpleData[1] = ",";
        simpleVector.add(simpleData);

        int i = 0 ;

        for (Iterator iterator = fullVector.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String[] object = (String[]) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(object);
            if(!simpleVector.contains(object)){
                System.out.println("test"+ i);
                i++;
            }

        }
    }
```

I want to find out the simplevector object findout fullVectorData object or not? why the contains method not giving desired result here?

Comment: I haven't seen `Vector` for a long time.. Why you're not using `ArrayList`?

Comment: By default array doesnt have equals method defined and you are storing string array and hence it compares reference rather than actual content.

Comment: In my application there is dependency with vector.We have no other option that's why we used vector.Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You add to `Vector` array Objects! So your `Vector` does't contain `String` it contains 3 Arrays of String.
You need to use

```
 fullVector.addAll(Arrays.asList(fullVectorData1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to test whether a particular string is present in vector but currently you are testing whether a `String[] array` is present in the vector. Change

```
simpleVector.contains(object)
```

To

```
for(int x =0; x < object.length; x++){
if(!simpleVector.contains(object[x])){
                System.out.println("test"+ i);
                i++;
            }
}
```

And also instead of adding array object into vector, you need to add String entries into the vector

Comment: Thank you.contains method checks element to element not with object?am i right?

Comment: @ramesh `contains` Returns true if this vector contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this vector contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of String in your Vector, hence you would need to use `Arrays.equals` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29) to compare two array's for equality as contains internally iterate over each element in vector and would check the references of two array element i.e. string array in your case. So you could do something like:

```
private static boolean doesContains(Vector<String[]> simpleVector, String[] object) {
  boolean doesContains = false;
  for (int i =0; i<simpleVector.size(); i++) {
      if (Arrays.equals(simpleVector.get(i), object)) {
        return true;
      }
   }
   return doesContains;
}
```

And call it like:

```
for (Iterator<String[]> iterator = fullVector.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String[] object = (String[]) iterator.next();
    if(!doesContains(simpleVector, object)){
        System.out.println("test"+ i);
        i++;
    } else {
      System.out.println("It contains");
    }

}
```